# Drupal 7 - Overriding Omega Theme's Temorary CSS Files

Tags: drupal-7

I have a problem with the Omega Theme's styling. I'm actually trying to do something very basic: To make the paragraph margin smaller. Normally I'd put stuff like that into `sites/all/themes/my_omega_subtheme/css/global.css` and it would work, but in this case it didn't.

So I debugged the webpage and it seems Omega puts some temporary CSS files into `sites/default/files/css` that are overriding `global.css`. So I guessed I would be able to change this in the appearance settings, but there aren't any settings for the paragraph margin. Of course I can't change the margin in there, either, because the files seem to be generated every now and then (at least the names are different today, and I made sure to not click save in the appearance settings).

Additionally I tried setting it with CSS ID and / or class because I thought this would surely override the temporary CSS file's value of `p { margin-bottom: 20px; }`, but it seems I'm just not informed properly.

So what is the correct way to set the paragraph margin in an Omega theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the CSS files stored in `sites/default/files/css` are the compressed CSS files which drupal generates automatically. To be able to make any changes appear as normal, you need to disable CSS compression.

Go to `?q=admin/config/development/performance` and un-check the option `Aggregate and compress CSS files.`

Now when you view the page source, you should be able to see a list off your theme's CSS files.

Comment: Thanks! That made me find the cuprit!